# Bash script in kubernetes deployment yaml

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes deployment yaml running some bash commands.

```
initContainers:
  - args:
      - command 1; command 2 && command 3; done;
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - --
```

I am trying to add a conditional if-statement to execute it run only if the dir is empty. This is what I have but it executes even when the dir is not empty.

```
initContainers:
      - args:
          - if [ -d "$DIR" ] && [ -n "$(ls -A "$DIR")" ]; then { command 1; command 2 && command 3; done; } fi
        command:
          - /bin/bash
          - -c
          - --
```